# Drupal: How to override a function from a contrib module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I am using a module that builds a price table for Drupal Commerce items. There is a function that formats the table headers:

```
/**
 * Helper function that takes care of the quantity displayed in the headers of 
 * the price table.
 */
function commerce_price_table_display_quantity_headers($item) {
  // Set the quantity text to unlimited if it's -1.
  $max_qty = $item['max_qty'] == -1 ? t('Unlimited') : $item['max_qty'];
  // If max and min qtys are the same, only show one.
  if ($item['min_qty'] == $max_qty) {
    $quantity_text = $item['min_qty'];
  }
  else {
    $quantity_text = $item['min_qty'] . ' - ' . $max_qty;
  }
  return $quantity_text;
}
```

As you can see, this is not a theme function where I can override it in template.php but I can to tweak some of the output.

**How can I redefine this function so I can chop and change a few things?**

*My work so far...*

So far, I have tried to create it as a seperate module with a few subtle changes to show if it's working or not, but it's not overriding any of the output.

**Info file**

```
; $id$
name = Price Table: Tweaked Display
description = A different layout for the price table as shown on the product display nodes
package = Commerce (contrib)
core = 7.x

dependencies[] = commerce_product
dependencies[] = commerce_price
dependencies[] = commerce_price_table
```

**Module File**

```
 /**
 * Override of the helper function that takes care of the quantity displayed in the headers of 
 * the price table.
 */
function commerce_table_tweak_display_quantity_headers($item) {
  // Set the quantity text to unlimited if it's -1.
  $max_qty = $item['max_qty'] == -1 ? t('Unlimited gnhh') : $item['max_qty'];
  // If max and min qtys are the same, only show one.
  if ($item['min_qty'] == $max_qty) {
    $quantity_text = $item['min_qty'];
  }
  else {
    $quantity_text = $item['min_qty'] . ' - this is working - ' . $max_qty;
  }
  return $quantity_text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most drupal modules I believe have a hook_function (or at least ones that are hookable) I don't do this much so I would search the drupal api for how to hook functions and if your module will support it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I asked at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40093/drupal-how-to-override-a-function-from-a-contrib-module and got a pretty decent answer